# Как найти видео на сайте при помощи javascript

Tags: javascript

Вот такая интересная задача, нужно обнаружить весь видеоконтент на сайте при помощи чистого javascript. Может есть решение как это лучше делать, не используя привязку к DOM, так как видео вставляется при помощи iframe и блоки могут быть рандомные

Comment: Если что-то вставляется через `iframe`, с `src` на другом домене, то вы не сможете получить доступ к контенту этого `iframe` из JavaScript. Совсем.

Comment: Поддерживаю комментарий выше, за исключением среды в котором этот скрипт будет исполнятся. Если это плагин или headless браузер, то вполне можно получить доступ к содержимому iframe без CORS. Вопрос в задаче: на лету обнаружить или просто вытащить откуда-то все источники видео?

Comment: Я думаю достаточно обнаружить `iframe` с `src` соответствующему шаблону. Это и будет видеоконтент.

Comment: @decyrus задача в том что-бы скрыть их просто от зрителя удалением его из дом дерева

Comment: @modelfak то есть это плагин к браузеру или страница во фрейме?

Comment: @decyrus страница во фрейме

Comment: @modelfak, тогда это невозможно, если только каждый из доменов-хостеров видео не разрешил CORS, это сделано из соображений безопасности и в современных браузерах уже не обойти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял что значит рандомные но в некоторых случаях такое сработает. Фильтровать регуляркой урлы, но вот залесть во фрейм с чужим доменом не удасться.

```js
var frames = document.querySelectorAll('iframe'),
  out = document.getElementById('out');

for (var i = 0, len = frames.length; i < len; i++) {
  out.innerHTML += frames[i].getAttribute('src') + '<br/>';
}
```

```html
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0UfDvWgJSnI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```
var urls = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('iframe')).map(function(iframe) {
    return iframe.src;
});
```